# JPA: Access an object from another object returns null

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I would like, from a key, to access the entity key above

The relationship is:

Rule contains a TermRule.
Each TermRule contains a rule and a variableConfiguration.

Only VariableConfiguration contains a Variable.

I would like, from TermRule, capture Variable.

I'm trying like this:

`termRule.getVariableConfiguration().getVariable()` and receiving null.

Its possible obtain the variable of a term?

```
public class Rule extends PersistentObject {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7852189080136935020L;

    @Column (name ="NAME", nullable = false)
    private String namerule;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "rule", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<TermRule> termRule;
}
//getters and setters
```

```
public class TermRule extends PersistentObject implements Comparable<TermRule> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 336244667983772321L;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_RULE", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Rule rule;
    
    @OneToOne 
    @JoinColumn (name ="ID_VAR_CONF", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = true)
    private VariableConfiguration variableConfiguration;
}
```

```
public abstract class VariableConfiguration extends PersistentObject {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4967631633375881594L;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_VARIAVEL", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Variable variable;
        
    @OneToOne (mappedBy= "variableConfiguration", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private TermRule termRule;
}

@DiscriminatorValue("Triangle")
public class Triangle extends VariableConfiguration {
}
```

```
public class Variable extends PersistentObject {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1172539974105845401L;

    @Column (name = "NOME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany (mappedBy= "variable", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<VariableConfiguration> variableConfiguration;
}
```

Comment: I understand that you skipped some fields/annotations for brevity, but TBH I can't see anything obviously wrong with your mapping. Can you please show us the code in which you're trying to access `termRule.getVariableConfiguration().getVariable()`?

Comment: Also, I understand `VariableConfiguration` is annotated with `@Entity`, right?

Comment: for (Variable var : variables) {
   termRules = getTermRule(rule) //list of termRules of rule
     .stream()
     .filter(termRule -> termRule.getVariableConfiguration().getVariable() == var)
     .collect((Collectors.toList()));         
  }
  return termRules;

Comment: VariableConfiguration is a @Entity

Comment: So the VariableConfiguration.variable property is null in your object graph - why do you think it should have a value? What is the value of the ID_VARIAVEL foreign key in the database, and how have you set this property in your object graph?